# iPhone Sencha Touch: In which JS / HTML file I need to start my application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have started implementing my application using **`phone gap and Sencha Touch`**.

I have added sencha touch sdk to my application using **`kitchen sink application`**.

When I execute the app it displays a list of user interfaces, etc on left side and a home page for sencha touch *kitchen sink app* on right side.

When I select any rows they shows buttons, lists, pickers and different types of demos as shown in *`kitchensink demo`*.

But **`I need to create my own views rather than kitchen sink demo views.`**

*`Here i have bundle of .JS & HTML files`* ***`in wich file i need to start my application`***,

How should i create a basic panel as initial step in which .JS file?

Comment: This sounds like it could be easily answered by reading the Sencha "Getting Started" documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is very easy, try put this into .js file. The code below is container main panel:

```
        var panel = new Ext.Panel({
        id:'pnlInit',
        fullscreen:true,
        items : [your_panel1, your_panel2, your_panel3, and_so_on],
        dockedItems: []
    })
```

where your_paneln are panel you created also into .js file. I hope these helps.

Comment: in your main .js file. e.g. your_name_main_panel.js and this execute the app it displays. :) So long.